# How to get the last item of the dictionary when looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know `dictionaries` differ from list and the "last" item is not meaningful in `dictionary` context. But I have a loop which iterates over a dictionary based on the user input, and then if the user input equals one of the keys, it shows a messages, otherwise, it checks to see if this is the last item of the dictionary, and if yes, shows a message that says "No such `dictionary`'s key has been found. Please revise your entry."

Here is the code:

```
dic  = {"Name" : "mostafa", "job" : "Animator", "Likes" : 'Smoking', 'target' : 'nothing'};

inp = input("Please eneter a key to show: \r\n");

    for item in dic :
        if(inp == item) :
            print("Thanks, found the key.");
            break;
        # Here I need an IF to check whether this is the last key or not
```

Comment: Why the loop? `if inp in dic:` should be all you need.

Comment: thanks a lot. For me as a newbie trying various ways is a good way of learning

Comment: @Matthias it's possible one wants to loop for other reasons but still wants to do something specific with the last item

Comment: @simplename: There is no "last" item in a dict until Python 3.7, and even then, doing something for the last item is extremely rare. In this case, it is clear that the loop is pointless, as it would be in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
for i, item in enumerate(dic):
    if (inp == item) :
        print("Thanks, found the key.")
        break
    if i == len(dic) - 1:
        print('This is the last key in the loop')
```

Also, it's easier to check whether a key is in a dictionary by doing:

```
if inp in dic:
    print("The key is in the dictionary")
```

Comment: thanks this is what I looked for. but sorry, why you substracted 1 from the length? isn't because i starts from zero?

Comment: Yes, so if there are three elements in the dictionary, the index will be 0, 1 and 2. So the last index will be 2 (which is 3 - 1).

Comment: it is faster to use the second method of course, but when I implement that, it always says it has not found, until I enter a key value than a value value....

Answer (score 1):

Looping over a dictionary to test whether a key is present defeats the benefit of using a dictionary in the first place. It is much, much faster to use

```
if inp in dic:
    # Found it.
```

If you need to run some code only when a loop isn't terminated by a `break`, you can use an `else` clause for that:

```
for item in thing:
    if condition:
        break
else:
    thing_that_only_happens_if_you_dont_break()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on an old question:
From python 3.7, `dict` has an insertion order, keeping the order of how items were initially inserted.

So the last item in a dict is `dict[list(dict.keys())[-1])]`
Example

```
>> d = dict(k1=(1,2),k2=(3,4),k3=(56))
>> d
>> {'k1': (1, 2), 'k2': (3, 4), 'k3': 56}
>> d[list(d.keys())[-1]] = 999
>> d
>> {'k1': (1, 2), 'k2': (3, 4), 'k3': 999}
```

OR

```
>> d[next(reversed(d.keys()))] = 1000
>> {'k1': (1, 2), 'k2': (3, 4), 'k3': 1000}
```

so in your loop:

```
if key == next(reversed(dic.keys())):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow:

print(dic.get(inp, "No such dictionary's key"))

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a solution BUT, I was thinking that it doesn't make sense to do this in a dictionary structure because dictionary keys are not ordered. Why do you want to do this?

Edit: Maybe you want to know the last key added? Maybe you can check the OrderedDict =)

Edit two: OR MAYBE you can check: if the input is in dic, then check if the index is equals to len(dic) - 1